# Record RTC unable to capture svg

Tags: javascript, svg, webrtc, html2canvas, recordrtc

**Problem Statement**  : I am trying to record the screen movements a user is trying to do. I would like to make a video out of it .

**Road block** : When trying to figure record the screen i am unable to record the svg content on the screen .

**Sample demo** (What i have tried) : http://codepen.io/rudi8292/pen/yJEAbd

```
 <svg width="100" height="100">
        <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
        Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
      </svg>
```

Does the library support recording of the ***SVG*** elements on the screen too ? I have searched enough in the library but couldn't find answer.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I finally solved this problem using Ccapture.js library. I had to capture some webGL components and some SVG Elements on the screen. I was using plotly graphs